# Determining the lists of graph edges have the same weights, and browse these lists in the decreasing order of their weights

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, graph-theory

Given a complete undirected weighted graph **G=(X,E)** such that, **|X|=n** and **|E|=(|X|^2-|X|)/2** and edges may contain duplicate weight values,
what is the data structure to determine the lists of edges **L_i** sharing the same weights, and listed in the decreasing order of their weights, say, **delta_i** :

```
L_1={(u,v), w(u,v)=delta_1} 
L_2={(u,v), w(u,v)=delta_2} 
...
L_m={(u,v), w(u,v)=delta_m}
```

The following properties must be verified:

```
delta_1 > delta_2 > ...> delta_m 

L_1 U L_2 U...U L_m=E
```

**Note** : **m** is the number of unique weight values in **G**

One simple way to do that is to use a balanced binary search tree where each node contains at least two information :

The key field **delta_i** to represent the weight of the edge list and the satellite data  **L_i** to represent the head of the linked list of edges with the same weight.
This representation of **G** requires (in the worst-case) **(|X|^2-|X|)/2** tree nodes and exactly **(|X|^2-|X|)/2** edge objects. We add to that the balance information and the parent-child pointers to maintain the tree, which is memory space consuming.

So my question is how do we efficiently represent these **m** edge lists and browse them in the decreasing order of their weights.

Comment: In java, you could use a SortedMap<Double, List<Edge>>, where the Double key to the SortedMap is the weight of the edges in that list.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does SortedMap implementation provide garanteed log2(m) time cost for the containsKey,get, put and remove operations as for TreeMap class. When adding an object <Double key,List<Edge>> to SortedMap , is the object's key compared to all the key values in the SortedMap which takes O(m) in the worst case. How elements are sorted (Sorting algorithm) in SortedMap. All these questions are important so i can improve the Time and Space complexity of my algorithm

Comment: SortedMap is an interface that TreeMap implements